# UnionTypes in HotChocolate

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I am trying to copy this GraphQL schema (don't have access to its code):
[image: TargetSchema]

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  role: UserRole!
}

type ForbiddenError {
  message: String!
}

type Mutation {
  login(input: LoginInput!): LoginOutput!
}

union LoginOutput = User | ForbiddenError
```

The frontend makes this request (and it cannot be modified):

```
mutation login{
  login(input:{usernameOrEmail:"user@example.com",password:"qwerty123"})
{
  ...on User{__typename id email role }
  ...on ForbiddenError{__typename message}
  }
}
```

I tried to create an interface that two objects, `User` and `ForbiddenError`, would share,

```
[UnionType("LoginOutput")]
public interface ILoginOutput
{
}
```

```
public class ForbiddenError : ILoginOutput
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User : ILoginOutput
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

```
public ILoginOutput Login(
    string usernameOrEmail,
    string password,
    [Service] IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    <...>
    if (...)
    {
        return new ForbiddenError();
    }

    <...>
    return user;
}
```

but in this case, I end up with the following schema:
[image: UnionSchema]
And error in request:

> Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "LoginPayload" can never be of type "User".

I tried to solve the problem by using an exception,

```
public class ForbiddenError : Exception
{
}
```

```
[Error<ForbiddenError>]
public User Login(
    string usernameOrEmail,
    string password,
    [Service] IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
     <...>
}
```

but I ended up with the following schema
[image: Exception]
And same error in request:

> Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type "LoginPayload" can never be of type "User".

How can I get the schema like the one in the first image? So that the specified query to GraphQL can be executed.

Comment: I don't speak GraphQL. But mimicking a `C` language union in C# is done by using a `struct` with `LayoutKind.Explicit`